Merging two word lists not working with position function
I've been trying to get a dictionary by mashing two different word lists together, but when I run it through Saxon it only repeats word #1 in wordlist2 on every row. It seems like Position() keeps returning 1 even though it's looping? I'm new to this so everything is pretty confusing.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="Lexicon" select="document('./Lexicon.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="URI1" select="$Lexicon/lexicon/wordlist1"/>
<xsl:variable name="URI2" select="$Lexicon/lexicon/wordlist2"/>
<xsl:variable name="URI3" select="$Lexicon/lexicon/icon"/>
<xsl:variable name="Wordlist1" select="document($URI1)"/>
<xsl:variable name="Wordlist2" select="document($URI2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="Icon" select="document($URI3)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$Icon"/>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <td colspan="2">Lexicon from <xsl:value-of select="document($URI1)/wordlist/@lang"/> to <xsl:value-of select="document($URI2)/wordlist/@lang"/></td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="$Wordlist1/wordlist/word">
          <xsl:sort select="."/>
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="$Wordlist2/wordlist/word[position()]"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>

I want it to list 10 words from file A, and then the 10 words from file B one word pair per row.

Perhaps you should  get position() from list1 and use it on list2.

Please provide a [mcve] by including the input.

Your stylesheet declares version="1.0" but you mention a Saxon processor. Please clarify which version of XSLT your processor supports. This is important if you want to sort the pairs.

@michael.hor257k I'm using SaxonJ-HE 12.4

See the addition to my answer.

Thank you @michael.hor257k I solved it from the input I received and some reflection, solution is posted below. Will remember for next time I ask a question here.

@KrulleBandhagen You tagged your question as position  and asked specifically about the position() function. Now it seems that your list items have an ID attribute that ties them together - which makes the position irrelevant and the entire problem a trivial one.

Consider the following simplified example:
XML
<lexicon>
   <wordlist1>
      <word>one</word>
      <word>two</word>
      <word>three</word>
      <word>four</word>
   </wordlist1>
   <wordlist2>
      <word>aaa</word>
      <word>bbb</word>
      <word>ccc</word>
      <word>ddd</word>
   </wordlist2>
</lexicon>

XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/lexicon">
    <xsl:variable name="list2" select="wordlist2/word" />
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="wordlist1/word">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$list2[$i]"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result (rendered)


Added:
To sort the pairs, create them in a variable first, then sort the result:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/lexicon">
    <!-- create the pairs -->
    <xsl:variable name="list2" select="wordlist2/word" />
    <xsl:variable name="pairs">
        <xsl:for-each select="wordlist1/word">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <pair from="{.}" to="{$list2[$i]}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$pairs/pair">
                    <xsl:sort select="@from"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@from"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@to"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

This will produce:
Result (rendered)


When an integer is used in a predicate word[N], it means word[position()=N]. So word[position()] means word[position()=position()], which is the same as writing word[true()].
The answer is to bind position() to a variable outside the predicate:
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$Wordlist2/wordlist/word[$pos]"/>


This works perfectly, but when I sort a column the other one remains in the original order. Is there a way to connect them so column B sticks to its counterpart in column A when sorting?

If the problem was solved, please select the answer that you found most helpful and mark it as accepted (by ticking the check-mark next to the answer). This helps future visitors to the site. It's also helpful to describe your solution in full: you can do this by editing the question or by adding your own answer.

Thank you everyone for the response, it made me think in new directions. This is the solution I ended up with:
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="Lexicon" select="document('./Lexicon.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="URI1" select="$Lexicon/lexicon/wordlist1"/>
<xsl:variable name="URI2" select="$Lexicon/lexicon/wordlist2"/>
<xsl:variable name="URI3" select="$Lexicon/lexicon/icon"/>
<xsl:variable name="Wordlist1" select="document($URI1)"/>
<xsl:variable name="Wordlist2" select="document($URI2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="Icon" select="document($URI3)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$Icon"/>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <td colspan="2">Lexicon from <xsl:value-of select="document($URI1)/wordlist/@lang"/> to <xsl:value-of select="document($URI2)/wordlist/@lang"/></td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="$Wordlist1/wordlist/word, $Wordlist2/wordlist/word" group-by="@ID">
          <xsl:sort/>
            <tr>
            <td><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/></td>
              <td><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[2]"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <td colspan="2">Lexicon from <xsl:value-of select="document($URI2)/wordlist/@lang"/> to <xsl:value-of select="document($URI1)/wordlist/@lang"/></td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="$Wordlist2/wordlist/word, $Wordlist1/wordlist/word" group-by="@ID">
          <xsl:sort/>
            <tr>
            <td><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/></td>
              <td><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[2]"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>


I'm a complete newbie and I didn't even know about the grouping feature, I added elements to group by in the source documents and then used the grouping by elements to get the elements in proper order for sorting. There are two tables in the finished code because I tried sorting by both columns. Works great!

This answer is not helpful to anyone because we cannot see the input.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
